# My code is giving an error, and I can't see why

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

*Warning: This will be long* (sorry)

I am using Tkinter in python, with PyCharm IDE. I am making a text-based rpg where you need to create an account to access settings which is all done and working. However, when you have previously made the account when logging in, if you then go back to main menu and try to login again right away it comes up with an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vandkb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Vandkb\PycharmProjects\VideoGame\main.py", line 8, in combined_func
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vandkb\PycharmProjects\VideoGame\main.py", line 161, in Login
    Settings()
TypeError: 'Tk' object is not callable
```

As far as I have been able to find, there is no reason why it shouldn't work. My code is as follows (it is long)

```
from tkinter import *
import json
import os

def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)

    return combined_func

#Title Screen

def TitleScreen():
    global TitleScreen
    TitleScreen = Tk()
    TitleScreen.geometry("980x470")
    TitleScreen.resizable(False, False)
    TitleScreen.title("Breaking the System  -  Main Menu")

    Title1 = Label(TitleScreen, text="Breaking", font=("Arial", 50, "underline"))
    Space1 = Label(TitleScreen, text="         ", font=("Arial", 50))
    Title2 = Label(TitleScreen, text="the", font=("Arial", 50, "underline"))
    Space2 = Label(TitleScreen, text="         ", font=("Arial", 50))
    Title3 = Label(TitleScreen, text="System", font=("Arial", 50, "underline"))
    Start = Button(TitleScreen, text="Start", font=("Arial", 20))
    Settings = Button(TitleScreen, text="Settings", font=("Arial", 20),
                      command=combine_funcs(SettingsLogin, TitleScreen.withdraw))
    Exit = Button(TitleScreen, text="Exit", font=("Arial", 20), command=Close)
    Developer =Label(TitleScreen, text="Developer: Kailan Van der Putten", font=("Arial", 10))

    Title1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    Space1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Title2.grid(row=2, column=2)
    Space2.grid(row=3, column=3)
    Title3.grid(row=4, column=4)
    Start.grid(row=5, column=0)
    Settings.grid(row=5, column=2)
    Exit.grid(row=5, column=4)
    Developer.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=NE)

#Account Creation

def AccountCreation():
    global AccountCreation
    AccountCreation = Tk()
    AccountCreation.geometry("980x470")
    AccountCreation.resizable(False, False)
    AccountCreation.title("Breaking the System  -  Create an account")

    global created_username
    global created_password

    AccountCreationRequest = Label(AccountCreation, text="Please create an account to access!",
                                   font=("Arial", 20))
    Space1 = Label(AccountCreation, text="          ", font=("Arial", 20))
    Username = Label(AccountCreation, text="Username:", font=("Arial", 15))
    created_username = Entry(AccountCreation, font=("Arial", 20))
    Password = Label(AccountCreation, text="Password:", font=("Arial", 15))
    created_password = Entry(AccountCreation, font=("Arial", 20))
    Create = Button(AccountCreation, text="Create", font=("Arial", 15),
                    command=combine_funcs(Acceptable, AccountCreation.withdraw))
    Back = Button(AccountCreation, text="Back", font=("Arial", 15),
                  comman=combine_funcs(TitleScreen.deiconify, AccountCreation.withdraw))

    Sword1 = Label(AccountCreation, text="         /", font=("Arial", 20))
    Sword2 = Label(AccountCreation, text="O===[====================-", font=("Arial", 20))
    Sword3 = Label(AccountCreation, text="         " + '\\', font=("Arial", 20))

    AccountCreationRequest.grid(row=0, column=0)
    Space1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    Username.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
    created_username.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
    Password.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
    created_password.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
    Create.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
    Back.grid(row=6, column=0)

    Sword1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=SW)
    Sword2.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
    Sword3.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=NW)

#Settings (Login)

def SettingsLogin():
    global SettingsLogin
    SettingsLogin = Tk()
    SettingsLogin.geometry("980x470")
    SettingsLogin.resizable(False, False)
    SettingsLogin.title("Breaking the System  -  Login")

    global entered_username
    global entered_password

    Login1 = Label(SettingsLogin, text="Login", font=("Arial", 20))
    Username = Label(SettingsLogin, text="Username:", font=("Arial", 15))
    entered_username = Entry(SettingsLogin, font=("Arial", 20))
    Password = Label(SettingsLogin, text="Password:", font=("Arial", 15))
    entered_password = Entry(SettingsLogin, font=("Arial", 20))
    LoginButton = Button(SettingsLogin, text="Login", font=("Arial", 15),
                         command=combine_funcs(Login, SettingsLogin.withdraw))
    Back = Button(SettingsLogin, text="Back", font=("Arial", 15),
                  command=combine_funcs(TitleScreen.deiconify, SettingsLogin.withdraw))
    DeleteAccount = Button(SettingsLogin, text="Delete Account", font=("Arial", 15),
                           command=combine_funcs(Delete))
    CreateAccount = Button(SettingsLogin, text="Create Account", font=("Arial", 15),
                           command=combine_funcs(AccountCreation, SettingsLogin.withdraw))

    Space1 = Label(SettingsLogin, text="          ", font=("Arial", 20))
    Space2 = Label(SettingsLogin, text="                    ", font=("Arial", 20))

    HP1 = Label(SettingsLogin, text="  _________", font=("Arial", 20))
    HP2 = Label(SettingsLogin, text=" {_________}", font=("Arial", 20))
    HP3 = Label(SettingsLogin, text=" )=======(", font=("Arial", 20))
    HP4 = Label(SettingsLogin, text=" /                \\", font=("Arial", 20))
    HP5 = Label(SettingsLogin, text="| _________ |", font=("Arial", 20))
    HP6 = Label(SettingsLogin, text="||                  ||", font=("Arial", 20))
    HP7 = Label(SettingsLogin, text="||                  ||", font=("Arial", 20))
    HP8 = Label(SettingsLogin, text="||                  ||", font=("Arial", 20))
    HP9 = Label(SettingsLogin, text="||                  ||", font=("Arial", 20))
    HP10 = Label(SettingsLogin, text="|\'----------------\'|", font=("Arial", 20))
    HP11 = Label(SettingsLogin, text="`-.................-\'", font=("Arial", 20))

    Space1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    HP1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    HP2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    HP3.grid(row=2, column=1)
    HP4.grid(row=3, column=1)
    HP5.grid(row=4, column=1)
    HP6.grid(row=5, column=1)
    HP7.grid(row=6, column=1)
    HP8.grid(row=7, column=1)
    HP9.grid(row=8, column=1)
    HP10.grid(row=9, column=1)
    HP11.grid(row=10, column=1)
    Space2.grid(row=0, column=2)

    Login1.grid(row=1, column=3)
    Username.grid(row=2, column=3)
    entered_username.grid(row=3, column=3)
    Password.grid(row=4, column=3)
    entered_password.grid(row=5, column=3)
    CreateAccount.grid(row=6, column=3)
    DeleteAccount.grid(row=7, column=3)
    LoginButton.grid(row=8, column=3)
    Back.grid(row=9, column=3)

#Login

def Login():

    global username2
    global password2
    username2 = str(entered_username.get())
    password2 = str(entered_password.get())

    with open("UserInfo.json", "r") as read_file:
        userword = json.load(read_file)

    if userword["Username"] == username2 and userword["Password"] == password2:
        Settings()
    else:
        Unmatched()

    read_file.close()

#Unmatched

def Unmatched():
    global Unmatched
    Unmatched = Tk()
    Unmatched.geometry("388x160")
    Unmatched.resizable(False, False)
    Unmatched.title("Breaking the System")

    Incorrect1 = Label(Unmatched, text="Username and Password are not incorrect.", font=("Arial", 15))

    Space = Label(Unmatched, text="      ", font=("Arial", 15))

    Done = Button(Unmatched, text="Done", font=("Arial", 15),
                  command=combine_funcs(SettingsLogin.deiconify, Unmatched.destroy))

    Incorrect1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    Space.grid(row=2, column=0)
    Done.grid(row=3, column=0)

#Delete

def Delete():

    global username2
    global password2
    username2 = str(entered_username.get())
    password2 = str(entered_password.get())

    with open("UserInfo.json", "r") as read_file:
        userword = json.load(read_file)

    if userword["Username"] == username2 and userword["Password"] == password2:
        os.remove("UserInfo.json")
        TitleScreen.deiconify()
        SettingsLogin.withdraw()
    else:
        Unmatched()

    read_file.close()

#Settings

def Settings():
    global Settings
    Settings = Tk()
    Settings.geometry("980x470")
    Settings.resizable(False, False)
    Settings.title("Breaking the System  -  Settings")

    Violence = Label(Settings, text="Level of Violence", font=("Arial", 20))
    Back = Button(Settings, text="Back", font=("Arial", 20), command=combine_funcs(TitleScreen.deiconify, Settings.withdraw))

    Violence.grid(row=1, column=0)
    Back.grid(row=2, column=0)

#Pause Screen



#Save Screen



#Inventory



#Info about person speaking



#The Game



#User Information

def UserInfo():
    List = {"Username": created_username.get(), "Password": created_password.get()}

    with open("UserInfo.json", "w") as write_file:
        json.dump(List, write_file)

    write_file.close()

#Acceptable

def Acceptable():

    global username1
    global password1
    username1 = str(created_username.get())
    password1 = str(created_password.get())

    if username1 == "" and password1 == "":
        Blank()
    elif username1.isspace() and password1.isspace():
        BothFalseWhite()
    elif not username1.isalnum() and not password1.isalnum() and not username1.isspace() and not password1.isspace():
        BothFalseSpChar()
    elif not username1.isalnum() or username1.isspace() or not password1.isalnum() or password1.isspace() or username1 == "" or password1 == "":
        BothFalse()
    else:
        SettingsLogin.deiconify()
        UserInfo()

#Blank

def Blank():
    global Blank
    Blank = Tk()
    Blank.geometry("388x160")
    Blank.resizable(False, False)
    Blank.title("Breaking the System")

    Incorrect1 = Label(Blank, text="Username and Password are not accepted,", font=("Arial", 15))
    Incorrect2 = Label(Blank, text="make sure to input letters or numbers.", font=("Arial", 15))

    Space = Label(Blank, text="      ", font=("Arial", 15))

    Done = Button(Blank, text="Done", font=("Arial", 15),
                  command=combine_funcs(AccountCreation.deiconify, Blank.destroy))

    Incorrect1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    Incorrect2.grid(row=1, column=0)
    Space.grid(row=2, column=0)
    Done.grid(row=3, column=0)

#Both False - Special Characters

def BothFalseSpChar():
    global BothFalseSpChar
    BothFalseSpChar = Tk()
    BothFalseSpChar.geometry("388x160")
    BothFalseSpChar.resizable(False, False)
    BothFalseSpChar.title("Breaking the System")

    Incorrect1 = Label(BothFalseSpChar, text="Username and Password are not accepted,", font=("Arial", 15))
    Incorrect2 = Label(BothFalseSpChar, text="make sure to input letters or numbers.", font=("Arial", 15))

    Space = Label(BothFalseSpChar, text="      ", font=("Arial", 15))

    Done = Button(BothFalseSpChar, text="Done", font=("Arial", 15),
                  command=combine_funcs(AccountCreation.deiconify, BothFalseSpChar.destroy))

    Incorrect1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    Incorrect2.grid(row=1, column=0)
    Space.grid(row=2, column=0)
    Done.grid(row=3, column=0)

#Both False - Only Whitespaces

def BothFalseWhite():
    global BothFalseWhite
    BothFalseWhite = Tk()
    BothFalseWhite.geometry("388x160")
    BothFalseWhite.resizable(False, False)
    BothFalseWhite.title("Breaking the System")

    Incorrect1 = Label(BothFalseWhite, text="Username and Password are not accepted,", font=("Arial", 15))
    Incorrect2 = Label(BothFalseWhite, text="make sure to input letters or numbers.", font=("Arial", 15))

    Space = Label(BothFalseWhite, text="      ", font=("Arial", 15))

    Done = Button(BothFalseWhite, text="Done", font=("Arial", 15),
                  command=combine_funcs(AccountCreation.deiconify, BothFalseWhite.destroy))

    Incorrect1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    Incorrect2.grid(row=1, column=0)
    Space.grid(row=2, column=0)
    Done.grid(row=3, column=0)

#Both False - One or both reasons

def BothFalse():
    global BothFalse
    BothFalse = Tk()
    BothFalse.geometry("388x160")
    BothFalse.resizable(False, False)
    BothFalse.title("Breaking the System")

    Incorrect1 = Label(BothFalse, text="Username and Password are not accepted,", font=("Arial", 15))
    Incorrect2 = Label(BothFalse, text="make sure to input letters or numbers.", font=("Arial", 15))

    Space = Label(BothFalse, text="      ", font=("Arial", 15))

    Done = Button(BothFalse, text="Done", font=("Arial", 15),
                  command=combine_funcs(AccountCreation.deiconify, BothFalse.destroy))

    Incorrect1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    Incorrect2.grid(row=1, column=0)
    Space.grid(row=2, column=0)
    Done.grid(row=3, column=0)

#Exit Function

def Close():
    TitleScreen.quit()

#Other Stuff


TitleScreen()

TitleScreen.mainloop()
```

Again I am very sorry the code is so long, I hope you can help.
Thanks.

Comment: how do I add the error into a quoteblock?

Comment: You've used the variable name `Settings` for at least three different things in this code.  Python can't read your mind to determine which of those things you intended to refer to, it just uses the most recent assignment.

Comment: I am unable to find anything that has to do with `Settings` other than inside the function `Settings():` and when in commands for any buttons, is this what you are talking about? Is it a problem that I've used it too many times for commands in buttons? or inside the function?

Comment: After you've assigned something else to that name, it no longer refers to the function, so any attempt to call that function will fail.

Comment: You have a function called Settings and a `Tk` window called Settings.

Comment: Ahhhh ok, I just tested my code again making sure the two had different variable names and it worked! Thank you so much!